# How to document HTTP POST/PUT data-binary upload in flask restplus swagger?

Tags: http, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

How to document HTTP POST/PUT data-binary upload in flask restplus swagger?

[flask plus swagger](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html)

I can simply use cURL command below to hit the service, but i not sure how to document it in swagger. Thanks

```
url -v -X PUT -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: {auth}' --data-binary "@data.zip"  http://localhost:18090/api?n=data1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do in swagger to document a file upload of any type:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=FileStorage, location='files', required=True)

@api.doc(id='upload', description='Upload file')
@api.expect(parser, validate=True)
def post(self):
    file = request.files['file']
    ...
```

Comment: the code above will generate multipart-form data which is the problem i facing.  In cURL it look like below 
```curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "file=@xxxx" http://localhost:18090/api?n=data1
```